# Pygame Joystick Control - Screen not updating?

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

I am trying to just move a given ball around the screen with a PS4 controller connected. I am able to connect the controller and have it return different values when moving the left analog stick. I feel as if the screen just needs to be updated? I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Here's what I've got:

Thanks

```
import pygame

def main():

     pygame.init()

     size = width, height = 800, 800
     black = 0, 0, 0
     speed = [5,5]

     screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
     ball = pygame.image.load("ball1.jpg")
     ballrect = ball.get_rect()

     pygame.joystick.init()
     joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(x) for x in 
 range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]

     for joystick in joysticks:
         joystick.init()

     controller = joysticks[0]

     while True:

         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

         ballrect.move(speed)
         if controller.get_axis(0) < -.5:
             speed[0] = -speed[0]

         if controller.get_axis(0) > .5:
             speed[0] = speed[0]

         if controller.get_axis(1) < -.5:
             speed[1] = speed[1]

         if controller.get_axis(1) > .5:
             speed[1] = -speed[1]

         screen.fill(black)
         screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
         pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rect.move](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) returns a new rect that you have to assign to the `ballrect` variable, e.g. `ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)`. Or use `ballrect.move_ip(speed)` which modifies the existing rect in place without creating a new rect.

The controller code seems to be broken as well. Try to do something like this:

```
# x and y axis positions of the stick (between -1.0 and 1.0).
x_axis_pos = controller.get_axis(0)
y_axis_pos = controller.get_axis(1)
# Set the speed to a multiple of the axis positions.
if x_axis_pos > .5 or x_axis_pos < -.5:
    speed[0] = int(x_axis_pos * 5)
else:
    speed[0] = 0
if y_axis_pos > .5 or y_axis_pos < -.5:
    speed[1] = int(y_axis_pos * 5)
else:
    speed[1] = 0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to set the speed to 0 if the value is not in the `if x_axis_pos > .5 or x_axis_pos < -.5:` range. Just add two `else` clauses.